# DataTables error with dynamic table row details

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables for a dynamically generated table (via ajax calls). The table by itself works fine but gives null exceptions with row details (works fine first time though), which point to the jquery.datatables.js code line 5388, after the first call:
"s is null on line:

`for ( i=s._iDisplayStart, iLen=s._iDisplayEnd ; i<iLen ; i++ )"`

Comment: Can you show the code in the errored lines? There are so many versions, your line numbers might not match the line number in the version I'm looking at.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.  While Datatables is reporting the error in jquery.datatables.min.js, there's a 99.9% chance the problem is in how you're making your call.

Comment: I posted the code. Thanks for your comments. I am using version 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working after I moved the row details click event methods to document.ready()

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you attach `.live` event handler. You have to use `.die` to unset it. Else you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, I bet that your image that you're clicking to expand/contract the rows is not the same as the image path you provided in this group of code:

```
/* Open this row */
 this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
 oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
```

Check your path and image name in this.src and ensure that it's proper.  Firebug or Chrome debugger are great ways to double check.

Comment: The path to the images is correct. The code works fine first time, but after second Ajax call I get errors.